# New Menu Changes the Template Folder's Path

Tags: php, joomla

I've created a menu with alias:diger. In this menu i've set it to show Articles » Category Blog. Whenever i get into a article in this menu i get a broken page and errors shown in the image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi19H.png

There's no folder in my ftp like "diger" do i have to upload it myself?
http://elizabet.getenjoyment.net/diger/templates/protostar/css/template.css

Comment: looks like a problem in your configuration .. diger shouldn't be there ;)

Comment: Yep the problem is that. Inside my main menu everything works fine i'm creating another menu let's say the name of menu is "about" and alias is the same.Inside that menu joomla tries to find the template files at /about/templates/protostar. But i want it to take template files from my normal installation.

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)).